# How to play streaming media via SMB protocol?

Tags: android, samba

I want to make an application to visit resources on Samba server. We can suppose that the server and Android device are in a LAN. I cache image files and text files before displaying them. But I think downloading videos to local storage isn't a good idea. Is there any way to play streaming media via SMB protocol? Please give me some tips.